# How to restart scrapy spider via os.execl

Tags: scrapy

Рlease tell me, is it possible to restart the spider using os.execl() in case of an error? If so, give an example of how to do this.
rough example of my go code

```
def parse(self, response):
    try
     ...
    except:
      os.execl("/usr/bin/scrapy", "crawl", "ruscale")
      os.kill(self.pid, signal.SIGKILL)
```

with this code I get an error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/scrapy", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 114, in execute
    settings = get_project_settings()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/project.py", line 68, in get_project_settings
    settings.setmodule(settings_module_path, priority='project')
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/settings/__init__.py", line 294, in setmodule
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'model_lavka'
```

Comment: Can I ask why you are trying to do this? Any errors you encounter while scraping should be handled with HTTP_RETRY codes or another method. If you are trying to do something else you probably want to operate a level above the spider and use a runner https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html

What is happening that you would need to restart the spider?

Comment: the thing is that, that errors are completely different, including those for which there are no exceptions, for example, inability to connect to a proxy server or loss of connection with mysql. In this case I need, so that the spider just starts to restart until it reconnects to the database or to the proxy server.

Comment: I would put all that logic in your pipeline to connect to sql server and such and if proxy fails it should auto retry I think.

Comment: OK I understood. Then maybe tell me how to handle such an exception?

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1418, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/downloader/middleware.py", line 38, in process_request
    response = yield method(request=request, spider=spider)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy_proxies/randomproxy.py", line 111, in process_request
    raise ValueError('All proxies are unusable, cannot proceed')
ValueError: All proxies are unusable, cannot proceed
`

Comment: how to retry the request to proxy

Comment: it should automatically retry